# Azure Security Center using too much storage

Tags: azure, azure-storage, securitycenter

I have enabled Azure Security Center a year ago. 
After one year, the Storage account that is collecting Security Center data is 1.5 terabytes in size and costs are starting to add up.

Is there a way to clear out old security data?

Is there a way to limit security/audit data to a certain period of time like 2 months?

Answer (score 1):

You can decide which types of raw data will be collected through *Azure Security Center* -> *Security policy* -> *your_subscription_name* -> *Edit settings* -> *Data collection* -> *Windows security events*.
The different choices for data collection are described in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/security-center/security-center-enable-data-collection#data-collection-tier).

To configure a retention policy, go to your *Log Analytics workspace* -> *Usage and estimated costs* -> *Data volume management* -> *Data Retention*.

On deleting old data from Log Analytics, I found [this](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/267889-log-analytics/suggestions/14757165-delete-logs-from-oms-workspace-by-type-date) answer on Azure forums (Jul 2018):

> Log Analytics cost is incurred when data is sent into the service.
>   Once the data has been made available for searching there is no cost saving by deleting the data (except in case of retention)
>
> That said, there are cases where it might be useful to delete logs.
>
> Specifically, to support GDPR, we have introduced Purge API – https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/log-analytics/log-analytics-personal-data-mgmt#how-to-export-and-delete-private-data
>   Please note that this API must not be treated as general-purpose data delete API, but used for GDPR purposes only